# Half pyramid of numbers

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, printf

I need to generate the following output of odd numbers in pyramid pattern.
The output will be like

```
1
3 3
5 5 5
7 7 7 7
```

I have written the following code. What portion i should modify?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int num,r,c;
  printf("Enter structure number : ");
  scanf("%d", &num);

      for(r=1; r<=num; r++)
      {
          if(r%2 != 0){
              m=1;
             for(c=1; c<=m; c++)
                printf("%d",r);
             printf("\n");
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Current  Output:

Current output is like-

```
1
2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: What is its current output? What is wrong with the code now? *(I didn't run or even read the code yet; this is something you should have explained in the question.)*

Comment: Change `printf("%d",r);` to `printf("%d",(2*r)-1);`

Comment: @TanjimaTani Please don't edit a question in a way that makes the existing answers appear invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write:

```
  for(r=1; r <= num; r+=2) //we only need odd numbers
  {
      times = r/2 + 1; //how many times to print odd number
      for(c=1; c <= times; c++)
          printf("%d",r); //print one character at a time
      printf("\n");
  }
```

You'll probably understand it better if you only iterate through odd numbers. I'm currently doing that and calculating how many times I need to print that number, then I'm just printing it as many times as `times` is.

Answer (score 3):

you have 2 errors in this code . 
m is not declared anywhere .
you are running a infinite loop

try this .

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int num,r,c,m;
  printf("Enter structure number : ");
  scanf("%d", &num);

      for(r=1; r<=num; r++)
      {
          if(r%2 != 0){
              m=r;
             for(c=1; c<=m; c++)
                printf("%d",r);
             printf("\n");
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, instead of

```
  m=1;
```

you should write

```
 m= ( (r/2) + 1);
```

Oterwise, all the time, you'll be iterating in the `for` loop only once.

Answer (score 1):

Some little modifications and it works:

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
 int num,r,c,m=0;
 printf("Enter structure number : \n");
 scanf("%d", &num);

  for(r=1; r<=num; r++)
  {
      if(r%2 != 0){
          m++;
         for(c=1; c<=m; c++)
            printf("%d ",r);
         printf("\n");
  }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

- m is undeclared
- line feed at the end of the printf message
- m incremented each odd iteration
- space between printed unmbers

Here is a [demo](http://ideone.com/N2fMlE).

Answer (score 1):

the inner `for` loop should look like this:

```
for(c=1; c <= r/2; c++)
            printf("%d ",r);
```

just think about it for a second. you want to print a rounded `r/2` of numbers in every line, right?

like: 
`3/2` -> 1.5 -rounded-> 1 -> prints: 3
`5/2` -> 2.5 -rounded-> 2 -> prints: 5 5
and so on.

you can run the code here on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/oM5noY)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num,r,c;
    printf("Enter structure number : ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for(r=1; r<=num; r++)
    {
        if(r%2 != 0){
            int m=r;
            for(c=1; c<=m; c++)
            {
                if(c%2 != 0){
                    printf("%d ",r);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

and test

```
sh-4.3# main                                                                                                                                                                          
Enter structure number : 9                                                                                                                                                            
1                                                                                                                                                                                     
3 3                                                                                                                                                                                   
5 5 5                                                                                                                                                                                 
7 7 7 7                                                                                                                                                                               
9 9 9 9 9
```

Answer (score 0):

In row 1, you should print 1. 
In row 2, you should print 3.
In row 3, you should print 5.
In row 4, you should print 7.
............................
............................
In row **n**, you should print **2*n-1**.

You can check this:

```
 #include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int num,r,c;
    printf("Enter structure number : ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    for(r=1; r<=num; r++)
    {
        for(c=1; c<=r; c++)
            printf("%d",2*r-1);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this:

```
for(r=1; r<=num; r+=2) // increment by 2, work for r= 1,3,5,7...
{
    for(c=1; c<=r; c+=2)// increment by 2
        printf("%d",r);
     printf("\n");
}
```

If you want alternate numbers like 1,3,5,7... just increment value by `2`.